# Lightbox2 not appearing online

Tags: javascript, jquery, lightbox2

I'm trying to use Lightbox2 image gallery (http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/) in the page, but nothing is appearing. I'm sure that has something to do with javascript ordering or something, I've added and linked all the files needed, but still nothing is appearing. You can see the place on http://www.art-service.lv/zonglesanasskola_new/students_jug.php, in that secondary navbar on the second tab, there's currently only title "Page 2".
Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

Actually, this problem is caused by your "tabs_old.js" file.

In its line 17-21, it has:

```
//hide two tab contents we don't need
var pages = tabcon.getElementsByTagName("div");
  for (var i = 1; i < pages.length; i++) {
  pages.item(i).style.display="none";
};
```

And these code hide all your DIVs in second tab (Page 2). When removed such style in Firebug(remove style="display:none;" in each DIV on Page 2), your Lightbox effect can be seen successfully.

So, you should modify or remove above lines to get your content correctly show on the page. In other word, it should be that only first level of Tab DIVs will have "display:none;" but not all DIVs. Otherwise, even if you set "display:block", it will only show the DIV that has specified class but not include its child DIVs that were hidden in the first place.

Comment: Thanks a lot, but I really have hard time following this, so I removed those lines in "tabs_old.js", then reloading the page, all the content shows on the first, default tab, when switching tabsit sort of shows the correct content, but still... In actual html I don't even have "display:none" on those divs in Page 2, it only shows that way in firebug, so yeah, I honestly have no idea what should I do, I obviously didn't get what you meant by all that. Like, litterally by steps what should I do to ?

Comment: Hi, You don't need to hide all of those DIVs and child-DIVs of tab page by javascript. First, remove those lines above. Second, use just normal CSS to hide all the tab pages. For example, you put:   .tabpage { display:none; }  in your CSS file. This will hide all tab pages by CSS. In this way, you will have the tab pages working.

Comment: Thanks a lot, okay, so I deleted those lines in javascript, created "tabpage {display:none;}", overally it works fine, but one thing - when I load page for the first time, it doesn't show any content, first tab is in selected mode, but the content of Tab visually appears only when I actually click on it. Any idea how to make the content of the first tab show automatically when page is loaded?

Comment: It is nice that your tab pages start to work. The above will hide all tabs in the first place, that's true. You have some ways to make the first tab show. 1. Use CSS: you can add style="display:block;" in the first Tab's DIV html tag. (inline CSS will override normal CSS, so the first Tab page will show when page load.) 2. Use JS: you can put something like jQuery('#tabpage_1').css('display','block'); or jQuery('.tabpage').first().css('display','block'); and both will make the first tab show when page is loaded. I think the CSS way will have a little better performance.